# I need add parents for childrens with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

Please, I need your help!!

I have code

```
<li>
      <p>–   dash1 </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>–   dash2 </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>–  dash3 </p>
</li>
   <p>text</p>

  <li>
      <p>1.   number1 </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>2.   number2 </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>3.   number3 </p>
</li>
<p>text</p>

    <li>
      <p>(1)   abc</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>(2)   abc</p>
    </li>
```

and I need add parent for group li

```
<ul type"DASH">
<li>
      <p>   dash1 </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>   dash2 </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>   dash3 </p>
    </li>
</ul>
  <p>text</p>
<ol type="ARABIC">
  <li>
      <p>   number1 </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>   number2 </p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>   number3 </p>
</li>
</ol>

<p>text</p>

<ol type="MANUAL">
    <li mark="(1)">
      <p>abc</p>
    </li>
   <li mark="(2)">
      <p>abc</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Thanks very much.

Daria

Comment: Can't you just put entire HTML code to XSL stylesheet ?

Comment: Do you need just to "add parent for group li"? Because also the contents changes in the desired output.

Comment: Which XSLT version are you interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code if you need parents for dynamic data code. However if you don't have dynamic input it's better to just put entire code into XSL stylesheet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <ul type="DASH">
            <xsl:copy-of select="/html/li[contains(p, 'dash')]"/>
        </ul>
        <p>text</p>
        <ol type="ARABIC">
            <xsl:copy-of select="/html/li[contains(p, 'number')]"/>
        </ol>
        <p>text</p>
        <ol type="MANUAL">
            <xsl:copy-of select="/html/li[contains(p, 'abc')]"/>
        </ol>           
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: i have input and output xml code.
 with your code output is
<html>
  <ul type="DASH"></ul>
  <p>text</p>
  <ol type="ARABIC"></ol>
  <p>text</p>
  <ol type="MANUAL"></ol>
</html>

Comment: @Dariake: I used `/html/li` endpoint, which assumes that input XML has `<html>` root (document) element with `<li>` (direct) child elements. Probably you need to change this endpoint. You can use absolute path like `/html/li` or relative `//li`, which just takes all `<li>` in input XML.

Comment: oh thanks, but now i have code
  `code`
<ul type="DASH">
    <li>
      <p>–   dash1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>–   dash2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>–  dash3</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>text</p>
  <ol type="ARABIC">
    <li>
      <p>–   dash1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>–   dash2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>–  dash3</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <p>text</p>
  <ol type="MANUAL">
    <li>
      <p>(1)   abc</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p>(2)   abc</p>
    </li>
  </ol>
`code`

no how question look

Thanks

Comment: Please describe what output you expect. There are some differences in your question such as `<li>` and `<li mark="(1)">` (MANUAL). I don't know why you have dash1, dash2 and dash3 in `<ol type="ARABIC">`. Function `contains(p, 'number')` should works well for input XML provided in your question .